# Django - best way for defining a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I wonder what is the best way for defining a many-to-many relationship in Django. Is this way correct?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class StudentTeacher(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What are the advantages of using `through`?

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='StudentTeacher')

class StudentTeacher(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extra_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: The difference is very well described by the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships Basically, both approaches work, however, with `through` table, there are some extra validations and meaningful restrictions in place so that you don't have to think about them.

Comment: @petr you should repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is in my opinion somewhat opinion-based, although still a valid question for SO. Therefore my answer will be to some extent also opinionated.

There is no absolute best way for doing it. Or better said, the best way always depends on the use case and on the requirements.

I would strongly prefer using `through` in this case (and probably more often).

How do you want to query your data? Having a `ManyToManyField`, where you would also specify `related_name` would result in readable and consequently maintainable code.

Let's take a look at this example (change in bold):

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(
        Student,
        through='StudentTeacher',
        related_name='teachers'
    )
```

Now the queries could look like:

```
it_student = Student.objects.get(pk=1)
it_teachers = it_student.teachers.all()
biology_teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=1)
biology_student = biology_teacher.students.all()
```

Now try to do these queries without specifying the `ManyToManyField`. The example is admittedly very simple, but should provide a basic idea about my thoughts.